# How to update item in array state in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Can someone tell me how I can fix the "updated" issue. I can't update the items dynamically, I can only update manually.

Here is mode code

```js
// Function (async) for rename the playlist and update
    const renamePlaylist = async (el) => {
        try {
            const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
            if (result !== null || result !== '') {
                /* let filterArrayRenamePlaylist = playList.filter((val) => {
                    if (val.id !== el ) {
                        return val;
                    }
                }); */

                console.log(el, ' --------- el');

                let renamePlayList = playList.filter((val) => {
                    if ( val.title === el ) {
                        let objIndex = playList.findIndex(obj => obj.title == val.title);
                        playList[objIndex].title = el; // it is not updated !
                        console.log(el , ' ----------- el 2');
                    };
                });
                
                // const updateList = [...renamePlayList ];
                setUpdate(context, {addToPlayList: null, playList: [...renamePlayList] });
                return await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(renamePlayList));

            }
            setRenamePlaylistModalVisible(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

When I try to manually update the playlist title like this:

```js
let renamePlayList = playList.filter((val) => {
                        if ( val.title === el ) {
                            let objIndex = playList.findIndex(obj => obj.title == val.title);
                            playList[objIndex].title = 'This works'; // This works
                            // playList[objIndex].title = el; // This does not works
                            console.log(el , ' ----------- el 2');
                        };
                    });
```

**I searched but couldn't find a solution to my problem.**

Answer (score 1):

lets take a closer look to your code and what your code is doing line by line, you made a few logical and code-style mistakes there:

```
let renamePlayList = playList.filter((val) => {
    if ( val.title === el ) {
    let objIndex = playList.findIndex(obj => obj.title == val.title);
        playList[objIndex].title = el; // it is not updated !
        console.log(el , ' ----------- el 2');
    };
});
```

Issue 1:
Do not write misleading functions, `filter` function should not modify anything, nobody will expect it to do that, side-effects are bad.Please, consider to separate Filtering and Modifying logic

Issue 2:
Filter function should return a value, true or false. In your case it returns nothing, void, so in the snippet above your `renamePlayList` will be an empty array, [].

Issue 3: The logical issue itself.

1. You do not need to seek objIndex, because you have the val element from same array AND array filter function itself do provide index of currently processing element, take a look at the docs please: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp (Syntax section)
2. `playList[objIndex]` is absolutely equal to your `val` object on first matching `val`, if you have more elements with same title - your findIndex code will return the first found element only, all the rest elements will be unchanged
3. Your val.title === el statement and playList[objIndex].title = el; makes no sense due to title is el in any case, like title was el and you are reasigning it to el, if it was "abc" reasigning it to "abc" will not change anything. Your `playList[objIndex].title = 'This works'; // This works` works exactly because you are setting a different value.

Based on that i would recommend changing your filter function to

```
playList
   .filter((val) => val.title === el)
   .forEach((val) => val.title = "new title or whatever you need here, not el btw")
```

This code will modify elements in playList, not sure if it is expected but if not - just make a deep clone of it before processing.
your setUpdate will need a little change also after that:

`setUpdate(context, {addToPlayList: null, playList: [...playlist] });`

Please, double check what your code is doing and what are you trying to achieve. My guess is that your top level function needs 2 parameters, like oldTitle and newTitle so it would be

```
playList
   .filter((val) => val.title === oldTitle)
   .forEach((val) => val.title = newTitle)
```

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is very well written and focused on teaching something. Keep it up @Sergey !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where I have to put the 2 parameters oltTitle and newTitle?  **const renamePlaylist = async (oldTitle, newTitle)** Is this where I should put?

Comment: Thats a good question for someone who gave you this task, you should replace old title with new title, and in your code you are replacing old title with.. old title again, thats why your code is "not working",, thats what my last part of the answer is about, i cant answer you until you provide more details about what you are doing, where data comes from, or at least some example about "i have this data and i want to modify it that way...". Im just missing the context here.

Comment: I know that I replace the old title with the old title but when I do "console.log(el)" I get the new title in the console why it does not happen the same way in the filter method?  [And here is the code snippet of my project](https://snack.expo.dev/@devops007/musicapp)  (path:...src/screens/PlayList and scr/components/RenamePlaylistModal)... PS: This my personal project ^^

Comment: I didn't put the whole project, I just shared the code which can shed more light on the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: I see, thank you but still, may i ask about the example of items inside `playlist` array, and clarify a little about the RenamePlaylist function, how you expect it to update value and on which entity? What is it doing currently - it accepts (el) as a parameter (please, use a better naming, i guess it should be named newPlaylistName) and it filters items in playlist based on THAT newName and trying to set that newName to the element found, but there is no elements with title = newName so no records affected.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the value entered in TextInput which is in another component then I want to replace the old value with the new value. you said there is no new record but yet i see the change when i do 'console.log(newPlaylistName)' in 'renamePlayList' function but i don't see when i do the same in `playList.forEach ((val) => { value title = newPlaylistName; console.log(newPlaylistName, ' --------------- newPlaylistName 2');
}`

Comment: I just updated the code, you can take a look

Comment: Yes, Modal component works as expected, it does return the newPlaylistName and you see it in the console log, no questions to this part, this string is passed as a parameter to a function,, it is ok, not ok is the part that is after that, the filter one and the assignment one, so please, tell me what you expect from this metod to do, because .filter is seeking an entry of the array with title === newPlaylistName, which is not what needed i think

Comment: What I expect from this method is to select the chosen playlist to rename the title (because they already have a title at the level of creating a playlist). For example, if the new playlist I created has the title "Rock", I want to select the playlist "Rock" and modify it with a new title. I do it with the filter method. I tried the .find, .findIndex, .map methods it gives me the same results. If I have to use another method which one would it be?

Comment: No other method in the Rename func will help you at this moment. Lets see your modal component and the RenamePlaylist func, neither of them is linked to an actual Playlist entry in any way, not by ID, not by any other criteria. Your Rename modal component is not inside of `playList.map` fragment (html) and you need to find a way to tell to the Rename func info about what exactly to rename. Like imagine you have 3 items in the playlist and you called Rename modal, which one you expect to be renamed (1,2,3) and why? Also, may i ask for the screenshot this page?

Comment: I select the element that I want, we can even see in the screenshots. [screenshots_1](https://ibb.co/ZM6LQjN)  [screenshots_2](https://ibb.co/gWztFV6)  [screenshots_3](https://ibb.co/0Dwk2Jk)  [screenshots_4 before the change](https://ibb.co/BZgbkNv)  [screenshots_5](https://ibb.co/99QYDhm)  [screenshots_6](https://ibb.co/Vxs8j3v)  [screenshost_7](https://ibb.co/mh1ChD7)

Comment: My 'renamePlaylist' function is linked to a playlist entry by "item.title" and not by "item.id" because I want to select the title
my 'renamePlaylist' function is linked to a playlist entry by "item.title" and not by "item.id" because I want to select the title

Comment: Ok, i got the picture, so what you need to do is:
1) add `const [selectedPlaylist, setSelectedPlaylist] = useState(undefined);` in the beginning somewhere
2) instead of 
`renamePlaylist(item.title);` write `setSelectedPlaylist(item)` (it is not a linking, it is a direct call)
3) instead of 
`.filter((val) => val.title === newPlaylistName )` do `.filter((val) => val.id=== selectedPlaylist.id)`
4) before `setRenamePlaylistModalVisible(false);` insert `setSelectedPlaylist(undefined)`

Tell me if that works and if no - update snack.expo.dev and we'll continue

Comment: Thank you very much it works as I wanted :D. Can you explain your solution to me so that I can understand the process please? Why `renamePlaylist(item.title)` is not correct?

Comment: Because i used the same method for 'removePlaylist' function (i did: `removePlaylist(item.id)` ) it works fine but not for 'renamePlaylist' i don't understand

Comment: Simply the execution flow, you need to see it, you need to play with debugger a little to understand step-by-step execution. `renamePlaylist(item.title)` was not correct because it was called once you click on Rename button. Even before Modal shows. You clicked Rename - this method was called (old title passed there as a param, filter found a record but didnt change anything), then modal shows up, you fill new name, then on callback this method was called again with new title (filter found NO record to change). Now this method has something to rely on, the state you added.

Comment: I even played a lot with the debugger putting 'console.log()' everywhere to understand but it didn't work on my part. Anyway, thank you very much, your solution solved my problem.